# Increase performance on Linq code in handling huge data

Tags: c#, performance, linq, where-clause

Please help me out in writing efficient code, Here is the code where adding items to `activeOrderEntities` list is taking longer time. Here `OrderEntities` has huge data (around millions of data).

```
var distinctIds = OrderEntities.Select(o => o.OrderCode).Distinct();
foreach (var id in distinctIds)
{
    var Entity = OrderEntities.Where(c => c.OrderCode == id).Select(x => x.Entity);
    var orderEntity = new OrderEntity {  Entity  = Entity.ToList(), OrderCode = id };
    activeOrderEntities.Add(orderEntity);
}
```

class object for OrderEntities

```
public class OrderEntity
{
    public string OrderCode { get; set; }

    public string Entity { get; set; }
}
```

class object for activeOrderEntities

```
public class ActiveOrderEntity
{
    public string OrderCode { get; set; }
    
    public List<string> Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so what's the current performance benchmark, what's the constraint you have to reach, what hardware are you using, and have you checked _where_ the bottleneck is?

Comment: Also please explain what you actually want to achieve - the code as shown is strange (looks like manual half-broken implementation of GroupBy) and thus does not really convey your goal.

Comment: I'd suggest doing a `GroupBy` on the `OrderCode` so you can get this down from O(n^2) to O(n)

Comment: Is it LINQ to Entities? If so, the question should clarify that.

Comment: Where is the performance issue that you would like to solve. Is it each iteration of the loop, so the sub-query, or is it the loop overall, or is it the commit at the end of this operation, different solutions would affect each of these aspects differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to get your data:

```
activeOrderEntities = OrderEntities.GroupBy(x => x.OrderCode).Select(x => new OrderEntity { OrderCode = x.Key, LogicalCatalog = x.ToList() }).ToList();
```

But I highly recommend to set index on `OrderCode` to get better performance and also set `Skip` and `Take` for prevent memory leak.